# Enable a function if a template parameter has a specific operator

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm currently implementing an optional type like the one in java and it would be nice if i could automatically implement all the operators that are present in the type that the optional wraps.

Example:

```
#include <optional>

struct nullopt_t
{
};

template <typename T>
class Optional
{
    // implementing the usual optional functionality
    // for the example just using std::optional
private:
    std::optional<T> stdOptional = std::nullopt_t{};

public:
    Optional(nullopt_t empty)
    {
        stdOptional = std::nullopt_t{};
    }

    Optional(T value) : stdOptional(std::make_optional(value)) {}

    template <typename R, typename Other, typename enabled = void>
    Optional<R> operator+(Other other);

    template <typename R, typename Other, std::enable_if</* some magic */>::value>
    Optional<R> operator+(Other other)
    {
        if (stdOptional)
            return Optional<R>(stdOptional.value() + other);
        return nullopt_t{};
    }

    // ...
};

struct Foo
{
};

struct Bar
{
   Foo operator+(Bar other);
};

int main()
{
    Optional<int> intOp{1};
    Optional<int> result = intOp + 1; // should work

    Optional<Bar> barOp{Bar{}};
    Optional<Foo> resultBar = barOp + Foo{}; // should also work

    Optional<Foo> fooOp{Foo{}};
    Optional<Foo> resultFoo = fooOp + Foo{}; // should not work
}
```

`/* some magic */` would check if the operator `operator+` has been implemented in `T`.

I would then apply `/* some magic */` for each operator that is available in c++ such that you can simply use them instead of checking the if your self or passing some lambda that does the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317175/template-template-class-call-a-function-if-it-exists

Comment: Aside: `std::optional` is C++17, not 11

Comment: If you can upgrade to C++20 (and have a compiler which fully supports C++20 concepts), you can use C++20 concepts for this.

Comment: Unrelated: I do not see any point of wrapping the `std::optional` with own Optional class. What is the use case?

Comment: What you are doing becomes exponentially easier with each increased standard version.  In [tag:C++14] it is easier than [tag:C++11], and in [tag:C++17] easier than [tag:C++14], and in [tag:C++20] it is easier than [tag:C++17].  Every indication is that it will be even easier in [tag:C++23].  Are you absolutely certain you are restricted to [tag:C++11]?  Also, have you tried blindly writing the operators with no magic tests?