# template struct declared twice for checking method existence

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, decltype

I am trying to understand that block of code found in an answer of this question : [template template class, call a function if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317175/template-template-class-call-a-function-if-it-exists)

```
template <typename T, typename = int>
struct HasReserve : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct HasReserve <T, decltype(&T::reserve, 0)> : std::true_type { };
```

The templated struct HasReserve is defined twice with different parameters. I guess, the second declaration is hidden due to SFINAE when T has no reserve method. But I do not understand how the compiler deals with this double declaration.

Comment: This is called [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). To put it short (**I'll be oversimplifying**): the compiler tries to match the template with the type. If the type type has reserve, i.e. its address can be taken, the compiler instantiates the matched type. If not, it falls back to the generic one, derived from false_type. Also, there is no double declaration. Class template != class. Imagine that no type is there until the first instantiation point.

Comment: So, when T::reserve exists, partial template specialization is 
template <typename T> struct HasReserve<T,0> : std::true_type{};
but 0 is not a type. How is it seen as a specialisation of <T, typename = int> ?

Comment: No, it's HasReserve<T,int>, note: `decltype(&T::reserve, 0)`. The first one checks if address of T::reserve can be taken (regardless if it's a variable or function, static or member, just cannot be a member reference) and then it's immediately discarded as the comma operator returns 0 which is passed to decltype. BTW, typically void and void_t is used for that purpose, unless you're on C++20 then concepts tend to be clearer. Small demo here: https://godbolt.org/z/TnGKo3vK9

Comment: I think I get it. decltype(0) is int, so when T::reserve is defined, partial template specialization is <T, int>. So it overrides any declaration HasReserve<SomeType> as the second template argument of the struct is int by default. Right ?

Comment: Don't quote me on this in terms of standard, but for for the sake of mental model this is correct.