# C++ concept for method does NOT exist

Tags: c++

I want a C++ concept for when a method does *not* exist.

My use case is to distinguish between a class that has two methods, and a class that only has one of them.

As it stands any `HasTwo` class is implicitly a `HasOne` class and I get an ambiguity error.

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct Do {};

// Has one or two methods?
template<typename T> concept HasTwo = requires { T::One(); T::Two(); };
template<typename T> concept HasOne = requires { T::One(); }; // want AND NOT TWO!

// For two methods call both
template<HasTwo T> struct Do<T> { static void Something() {
    T::One();
    T::Two();
}};

// For one method call the one
template<HasOne T> struct Do<T> { static void Something() {
    T::One();
}};

// Example classes
struct WithOne { static void One() { std::cout << "1"; } };
struct WithTwo { static void One() { std::cout << "1"; } static void Two() { std::cout << "2"; } };

// Example usage
int main() {
    Do<WithOne>::Something();
    Do<WithTwo>::Something(); // ERROR! more than one partial specialization...
}
```

Comment: split `concept` (allow subsumption), or `!requires(..)`?

Comment: Here is a solution without concepts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55282226/2527795

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nnsKrn5rT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make concepts subsume each other, you need to define concepts in term of each other:

```
template<typename T> concept HasTwo = HasOne<T> and requires { T::Two(); };
```

Just doing that change will prioritize the function correctly.

If you really want to check the absence of a method, you can also do this:

```
template<typename T> concept HasTwo = not HasOne<T> and requires { T::Two(); };
```